.NET MAUI IsEnabled reset edit value
Strage behaviour
I populate my viewmodel properties (one of them locks fields)
 public partial class ConfigurationViewModel : ObservableObject
 {
     [ObservableProperty]
     private WDXConfiguration? _configuration;

     public ConfigurationViewModel(WDXConfiguration? Configuration,bool newFirstTime)
     {
         _configuration = Configuration;
         FirstTime = newFirstTime;
     }

     [ObservableProperty]
     private bool _firstTime;
 }

 public partial class WDXConfiguration : ObservableObject
 {
     public WDXConfiguration()
     {
     }
     
     [ObservableProperty]
     private string _codFiscale;

     [ObservableProperty]
     public bool Enabled{ get;  set; }

     public void Load()
     {
      //test
      CodFiscale="ABCDE";
      Enabled=false; 
      }
}

public ConfigurationPage(ConfigurationViewModel model)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = model;
    //also tried to unlock/set/lock
/*
I tried this way AFTER I've seen that automatic MVVM field value assignment  FAILED

Commenting the lines below makes NO difference in result.
*/
    if (model.Configuration != null)
    {
        CodFisc.IsEnabled = true;
        CodFisc.Text = model.Configuration.CodFiscale;
        CodFisc.IsEnabled = false; //<== **if I comment this line WORKS (SEE IMAGES BELOW)**
    }
}

Page sample
<ContentPage
    x:Class="VTR_Mobile.Views.ConfigurationPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui/design"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VTR_Mobile.ViewModel"
    xmlns:cls="clr-namespace:VTR_Mobile.Classes"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VTR_Mobile.Views"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    Title="Aggiunta configurazione"
    x:DataType="vm:ConfigurationViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d">


    <StackLayout>
        <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#30aaaaaa,Dark=#30cccccc}" Margin="10,10,10,10" >
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#666,Dark=#fff}" FontSize="11" Text="Codice Fiscale" Margin="10,10,10,0" />
                <Entry TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#333,Dark=#aaa}" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Configuration.CodFiscale, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="CodFisc"  IsEnabled="{Binding Configuration.Enabled}" Keyboard="Text" MaxLength="6" TextTransform="Uppercase" Margin="10,0,10,10" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Border>
    <StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

My code
WDXConfiguration config=new();
config.Load();
ConfigurationViewModel  vm=new(config,true);
ConfigurationPage page = new ConfigurationPage(vm);
Application.Current.MainPage = page;


If possible, I want that value is shown to user, but it is not possible to modify. I have not used labels instead of edit because in first pass user enter values, in the second (maybe later) it's only to confirm them (and must be locked).

you are using both databinding and direct assignment to set the value of IsEnabled.  Pick one approach or the other

@Jason I've tried indipendently both ways... none of them work (if I comment manual assigment result is the same, no values shown)

When using MVVM never set the value of the control x:Name="..." from the code-behind  it will lose its binding
So, remove x:Name="CodFisc" or use it to get data only if required.

WDXConfiguration Class:
This is incorrect public bool Enabled { get; set; }
either use enabled or _Enabled and use it by uppercase Enabled=...
It should be like this:
[ObservableProperty]
public bool _Enabled;

OR
[ObservableProperty]
public bool enabled;


public ConfigurationPage(ConfigurationViewModel model)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = model;
    //also tried to unlock/set/lock
    if (model.Configuration != null)
    {
        //REMOVE THIS >> CodFisc.IsEnabled = true;
        //REMOVE THIS >> CodFisc.Text = model.Configuration.CodFiscale;
        //REMOVE THIS >> CodFisc.IsEnabled = false; //<== **if I comment this line WORKS (SEE IMAGES BELOW)**
        
        //To modify the values use model.Configuration.xxx=yyyy; directly
        model.Configuration.Enabled= true;
        model.Configuration.CodFiscale = "ABC";
        model.Configuration.Enabled = false;
    }
}

<StackLayout>
        <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#30aaaaaa,Dark=#30cccccc}" Margin="10,10,10,10" >
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#666,Dark=#fff}" FontSize="11" Text="Codice Fiscale" Margin="10,10,10,0" />
                <Entry TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#333,Dark=#aaa}" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Configuration.CodFiscale, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding Configuration.Enabled}" Keyboard="Text" MaxLength="6" TextTransform="Uppercase" Margin="10,0,10,10" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Border>
<StackLayout>


in docs it's ok if you user _enabled (it works fine, values are stored),
WON'T WORK , I've deleted name assignation, no values shown... in fact if it loses binding WHY if I let the field to be read-write value are read (also via MVVM) even when I set the field name?

EDIT: the point is that there's NO importance the way I assign the value (via MVVM or via setting manually in constructor).. when I set the field as read-only value disappears.. a control in modelview shows values but in view edits are empty...
